# $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, f(x) =⌈x⌉ $, Indicate which of the three properties: 1) everywhere defined, 2) onto, and 3) one-to-one

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am struggling to decide the answer to this. I know for a fact it is everywhere defined, and **NOT** one-to-one. However, Is this function considered onto? Since in my thinking every x you put in (mapped from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$) is being mapped. Since when you plug in a real number you will get back an integer no matter what.

Comment: What you described is everywhere defined, as to being onto what you want is that for every integer $n$ you can find at least one $x$ such that $f(x) = n$.

Comment: Onto:  For ony integer $z$ can you always find at least one real $x$ so that $\lceil x \rceil = z$.  What $x$ will give you $\lceil x \rceil= 0$.  $\lceil x \rceil  = -3$.  $\lceil x \rceil  = 14$.  Can you generalize to always find an $x$ for every integer?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.**

1. You are correct. It is defined everywhere.
2. You are correct. It is not one-to-one, $⌈3⌉=⌈2.7⌉=3$
3. To be surjective, given any integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, you want an $x$ so that $f(x)=⌈x⌉=n$. For this, think $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Can you think of something that 'hits' every integer?